# How can I check Vue CLI version?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli

If I run `vue --version`, the result is `3.11.0`

Does that mean I use vue-cli 3? How do I know I am using vue-cli 2 or vue-cli 3?

Comment: `vue --version` tells you the CLI version. `3.11.0` is indeed vue cli 3.

Comment: This is for global vue cli version. How can I know which version is being used in my project??

Comment: @RitikPatni, go the folder of your project with the terminal and run the same commands.

Comment: @tadvas Yes that's what I tried and it shows @vue/cli 4.0.5 even though the project is built on vue/cli 2

Answer (score 50, accepted):

version of vue cli

```
vue --version
```

version of vue

```
npm list vue
```